# Why php-fpm warning respawning children?

Tags: php

When my server receives many requests php-fpm records (php5-fpm.log) the following:

```
WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 6 total children
```

My php-fpm.conf is:

```
    ...
    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 50
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3
    pm.max_requests = 200
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to change your php-fpm.conf.

```
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

As php-fpm.log shows,[pool www] seems busy.There are 6 total children and php-fpm will spawn 8 more.It means that there are not enough php-fpm processes. I suggest you increase pm.start_servers,pm.min_spare_servers and pm.min_spare_servers based on your server performance.

Comment: Do you have any way to calculate this?
Based on the amount of memory and processors...